# Can here be SQL Injection

Tags: web-application, php, mysql

i got till moment when i do not know if it is secure!

If SQL injection is inserted into `myTableTwo` via safe PDO query will it make my query below SQL injection open? Is the query below safe?

`$mysfield` returns SHOW COLUMNS FROM `myTable`

`myTable` columns match `myTableTwo` columns

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (".$mysfields.") SELECT ".$mysfields." FROM myTableTwo");
$sql->execute();
```

**EDIT**
This is how i insert into `myTableTwo`

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO myTableTwo (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sql->execute([$value1,$value2]);
```

Comment: It's not unsafe, but you are using PDO and prepared statements wrong. If you copy this code to use unsafe input, **you will get pwned!**

Comment: @MechMK1 i m not sure if i follow. .. I added my first insert query in question. .

Comment: The way you insert into `myTabletwo` is correct. That's how it's supposed to be. But the first kind is simple string concatenation. If you use that with attacker-controlled data you will get pwned.

Comment: @MechMK1 the only real question is: Is `INSERT INTO myTable (".$mysfields.") SELECT ".$mysfields." FROM myTableTwo` safe no matter where i run it? If we know that `$mysfield` returns SHOW COLUMNS FROM `myTable` lets keep in mind that data in `myTableTwo` comes from user input

Comment: The existing answers already provide this information. What I am trying to convey is that you are using potentially unsafe code and you should be aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program might not be vulnerable because of some restrictions you have (maybe the variables cannot be changed by any user input), however I still think you are using prepared statements incorrectly.

Prepared (or parametrized) statements are meant to be used with "parameters" in order to be secure against SQL injection. In other words, the statement should be like a "template" with parameters. Then you will have to bind the variables to the parameters. See the examples at https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php for example, where you will see that the parameters in the statement look like `:param`, and are not actual variables like `$param`. Using parameters in that way is the only way to achieve separation between code and data, so that SQL injection will be prevented.

Comment: I know how it works: `$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO myTableTwo (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sql->execute([$value1,$value2]);` <--- this is how my first insert looks

Comment: @Ingus, ok, good, so the problem you have is that you need to build a specific statement using variables. In that case, check if you *really* cannot do it with parameters. If you really can't, then it's ok to build your statement using variables, but you need to make sure that those variables cannot contain any user input (the content of the variables is predetermined by you).

Comment: This is what i m asking. .. Knowing that data in `myTableTwo` are inserted by user input is it safe to insert data from `myTableTwo` to `myTable` as i do in example above (insert select)?

Comment: @Ingus, yes, as long as user input cannot end up in the variables. In your case, I guess the only variable is `$mysfields`, which contains the names of the columns. If you are sure that those column names cannot be influenced by any user input, then it is safe to use that variable inside the query.

Comment: Ok nice! No `$mysfield` variable can not be affected by user! Just to be sure! Even if some value in `myTableTwo` column contains SQL injection will it be a bad thing on `INSERT INTO myTable (".$mysfields.") SELECT ".$mysfields." FROM myTableTwo`?

Comment: @Ingus, no, the only thing you need to worry about in that query is the `$mysfields` variable. Anything else doesn't count, the actual contents of the tables don't count.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting w3schools here:

> Prepared statements are very useful against SQL injections, because parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement template is not derived from **external input**, SQL injection cannot occur.

So, yes your Statement should be safe

Comment: A prepared statement is a way which **permit** to avoid SQL injection but it is absolutely not a way which **avoid** it. You can still have SQL injection with a prepared statement

Comment: @Sibwara what could you tell bout my question? On my point i think that if SQL injection is inserted in database (even if with prepared PDO) it is not secure on my preview insert query!?

Comment: Your request seems to be secure for me but I'm not an expert of SQL injection. My comment was just a warning to keep in mind that using a prepared statement is not sufficient to achieve SQL injection avoidance

Comment: `$myfields` will be properly escaped and treated as data, even if it comes from another table. While yes Sibwara was right to mentions that it is possible to mess up prepared statements, the one in questions here still seems fine.

Comment: @Mindslave Ok thanks for your answer! I will hold for other answers for now to see if there are other opinions :)

Comment: Most importantly, the statement doesn't come directly from external input, which is the key to the injection

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ So in this case any SQL injection type text will be considered just as text?

Comment: I mean that in order to trigger an injection attack, the SQL statement must be formed at least from some external input. If you use only your application's logic to generate the statement, there are two cases: 1) if you have an incorrect escape (a bug) and certain conditions trigger an unwanted result, but the chances that it can be used for an attack are close to zero because the attacker can't control the text, 2) your code is not vulnerable

Comment: Of course "external input" is not necessarily get/post parameters. If you depend on values stored in the database **that the attacker can control**, then they can save a user names *Little Bobby Tables*, for which I redirect you to [this mandatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 2):

This is safe against SQL injection, because the `$mysfields` variable cannot be influenced by an attacker. However, it is still a good idea to properly escape all column names. This makes SQL injection impossible, and also prevents problems when using [reserved keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889871/how-do-i-escape-reserved-words-used-as-column-names-mysql-create-table) as column names.

The way to do this is when constructing `$mysfields`. Presumable you get an array with column names. Escape each column name, according to the method used in your database. Often, this is done by escaping any quotes and then surrounding the value in quotes. If there is a function for that in your database library, use that. Then, join all escaped values with commas in between.

Of course, if you use a [ORM library](https://www.doctrine-project.org/), you won't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 2):

First, this `SELECT` is a little strange. Unless both tables have the same structure, you cannot run an `INSERT` from one to another. In this particular case, `myTableTwo` probably is a copy of `myTable`, but not always this will be true.

Second, using prepared queries without binding the parameters is as unsafe as using `mysql_query()`. You are putting a variable straight into the query. It's not a prepared query.

> $mysfield returns SHOW COLUMNS FROM myTable

So why not use `SELECT * FROM myTable`? It makes more sense, it's shorter, and there's no way to inject anything.

Since MySQL 8.0.19, there's even a new way to do so:

```
INSERT INTO myTableTwo TABLE myTable;
```

Comment: Sometimes multiple things makes sense but in project where we are not rebuilding i have to use what is made

Comment: also i have told that myTable columns match myTableTwo columns